# Nature of critical point

Tags: functions

This is the given function

$$f(x, y) = x^4- 2(x^2)(y^2)+ y^4 +y^3$$

I have calculated the critical points to which I get $(0,0)$ and $(0,-3/4)$.

$$
f_{xx} = 12x^2- 8y \\
f_{yy} = -4x^2 +12y^2 +6y \\
f_{xy} = -8
$$
but
when I calculate hessian for $(0,0)$, I am getting $8$ and $f_{xx},\ f_{yy}=0$ for which I am confused how do I determine the nature of critical point $(0,0)$ 
Can somebody help?

Comment: i think there are no extrema

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to answer these kinds of questions is to use the Hessian.
$$
H(x,y) =
\begin{bmatrix}
12x^2 - 4y^2 & -8xy \\
-8xy & -4 x^2 + 12 y^2 + 6 y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You will notice that at $(0,0)$, the Hessian is zero and the Hessian test is inconclusive about whether the critical point is a min/max or saddle point.

When you have this situation, you have to look at the function a different way to classify the critical points.

We can try to evaluate $f(x,y)$ for a specific slice and determine the behavior of that. So let's calculate it for $y=x$.
$$
f(x,x) = 48x^3
$$
Along this slice, we see that $(0,0)$ is an inflection point. Note that any point which is an extrema would stay an extrema when looking along any direction. So if a point is not an extrema along a specific direction, then it cannot be an extrema of the original function.

Thus, $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.